# Accessing data in an object generated from table rows with keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I generated (an array of?) following object (json?) using the below code applied to a table with key identifiers for row, but I'm not sure I properly understand it. Can you give me an idea of how to access an item in this array/object using the key and the item number as an index? Using the regular variable[][] method doesn't work in this case.

The object (tableData):

key: key: 1
values: (3) […]​​
0: "D"
1: "E"​​
2: "F"
length: 3
values: Array(3) [ "D", "E", "F" ]
: {…

(etc. etc for each key)

The Javascript:

```
    $("#btn1").click(function(){

      var tableData = $('tr[data-key]').map(function(){
       var $row= $(this), key = $row.data('key');
        var values= $row.find(':input').map(function(){
            return this.value
        }).get();    
        return {
            key:key,
            values:values
        }
    }).get();


})
```

The HTML table:

```
<table class="table order-list">
  <thead>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr data-key="1">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="D"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="E"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="F"></td>
  </tr>

   <tr data-key="2">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="H"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="I"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="J"></td>

    </tr>


       <tr data-key="3">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="K"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="L"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="M"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>



</table>


<button id="btn1" style="width:100px, height:100px">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.get() returns an array, rather than an object. You'd have to access the array by the index. So, if I wanted, say the F cell - it would be tableData[0].values[2].

tableData gives me the array, tableData[0] gives me an object of {key: 1, values:["D", "E", "F"]}, tableData[0].values gives me the values array of ["D", "E", "F"], tableData[0].values[2] gives me the value at index 2 of that array. Hope that helps.

Comment: Corey, thanks so much for your help. The other responses really helped with my understanding but this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your data and it's an array of object. You can access any array using it's index and you can access any object value using it's property name. You can check my solution.

```js
console.clear();

$("#btn1").click(function(){

      var tableData = $('tr[data-key]').map(function(){
       var $row= $(this), key = $row.data('key');
        var values= $row.find(':input').map(function(){
            return this.value
        }).get();    
        return {
            key:key,
            values:values
        }
    }).get();

  const firstRow = tableData[0];
  console.log('first row:', firstRow)
  console.log('key of first row:', firstRow.key)
  console.log('values of first row:', firstRow.values)
  console.log('single value from first row values:', firstRow.values[0]);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <table class="table order-list">
  <thead>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr data-key="1">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="D"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="E"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="F"></td>
  </tr>

   <tr data-key="2">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="H"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="I"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="J"></td>

    </tr>


       <tr data-key="3">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="K"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="L"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="M"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>



</table>


<button id="btn1" style="width:100px, height:100px">Click</button>
  
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer that makes a lot of sense! So I see you've declared a new variable 'firstrow' in order to access the values - does that mean you can't access them in a direct fashion with 'tableData'? Also if so, would it be possible to make 'firstrow' into an array of its own ('i.e. row'), allowing access along the lines of row[1].values[0]?

Comment: Edit: That question seems to have been answered below! Thanks again! Have a great day Sifat :)

Answer (score 1):

To just solve this with the code you have, you can do this:

```
const tableData = // tableData
const row1 = tableData[0];
const row1Values = row1.values;
const row1Value1 = row1Values[0];
```

So the data you have isn't that complex, it's just not very intuitive for what is a table, and the key property isn't being used.

Rather you might want to rewrite your code so that you get table data which is a two dimensional array ([][]).

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    const tableData = $('tr[data-key]').map(function () {
        const $row = $(this);
        const key = $row.data('key');

        const values = $row.find(':input').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        return values; // This is the only line that really changed
    }).get();
})
```

PS.
I would recommend getting in the habit of not declaring multiple variables in the same row with the same keyword, it makes your code easier to read, for yourself and others but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you Milton! I've been looking at this, and it seems much more straightforward and managable. It also helped me to understand the use of the $ to define a representation of the object. Have a good day!

Comment: Glad I could help, with both the first and the second version of the code you can of course access the data more directly. In the first like `tableData[0].values[0]`, and in the second `tableData[0][0]`, so really quite minor differences but mentally it feels like an extra step to first have to reach into `values`!

Comment: Perhaps if it was named columns it would make it easier :)